# Why CAs instead of global fingerprint database?

Tags: ssh, certificate-authority

Why do we use "too big to fail" CAs and the chain of trust instead of a global fingerprint database in a similar vein to how ssh works?

Comment: Who maintains the database? In particular, who has the right to add fingerprints to it? What happens when it's down?

Comment: BTW we're using a bit in that direction by having DNSSEC deliver fingerprints (DANE).

Comment: For example, IANA. Owner of a particular domain (maybe smth akin to editing DNS zone records, which would later be parsed and fingerprints collected by root servers for particular tlds). Like CA certs, fingerprint DB should be included with the OS (to subvert spoofing) and updated by OS maintainers.

Comment: Wait, so you are suggesting that every OS ships with millions and millions of fingerprints for every website that uses certificates? That's impratical because of (1) the sheer volume and (2) turnaround/update times.

Comment: Not every website needs https (why do one needs https for personal homepage/blog, web dictionary, wikipedia, your average news site), we can have centralized authentication like open-id and furthermore fingerprints do not change without a reason, therefore list would be rather small and updates really won't be huge in size. If an institution manages to lose its private key, it's its own fault that new fingerprint is not propagated immediately, imho.

Comment: @User145678 Yes, every website does need one. If only the private data is encrypted, encryption becomes suspicious. Privacy is becoming more and more of an issue. But this is besides the point. Even if there were only 1 million fingerprints, that would mean close to 3000 updates every day, assuming an even distribution. The solution is delaying updates, but I wouldn't want to have to wait a month to get my webshop https-enabled.

Comment: @User145678: Even if it were feasible, I'm still not sure how your proposed system makes things better. At the moment, you have to trust your browser vendor to supply a valid list of root certs, and then you can choose which of these to trust. Under your system, you'd have to trust your OS vendor and a single global fingerprint provider. In my eyes, this makes the trust problem and the 'too big to fail' problem worse in both cases, not better.

Comment: So, instead of several "too big to fail" CAs, you recommend replacing it with one "too big to fail" fingerprinting authority? :)

Comment: @Luc How many times did you see https secured site changing it's EV certificate in a year? Fingerprint has no valid time limit - it can be used forever. If you changed fp and user didn't have recent db, your site would work with a big red warning. User could verify the fingerprint himself.

Comment: @us2012 Now you trust CA's and the browser vendor (multiple points of failure) You would be able to install/update this list yourself or leave it to your OS maintenance team (one point of failure - global db). My system would remove CAs as points of trust and control, consequently system would be more decentralized overall. Control for the most part would be in the hands of the owners of domain.

Comment: @mricon Look above.

Comment: There are still two points of failure, the OS maintenance team and the global DB. Unless you expect each OS to have their own 'global DB', in which case it isn't global anymore and everyone acquiring a new cert would have to talk to a couple hundred OS maintainers. And you still haven't adressed why your global DB is not 'too big to fail'. Right now, we can let a CA go down/bankrupt if they screw up, even if it's difficult to manage. If the global DB is compromised and loses people's trust, there is no alternative anymore.

Comment: @us2012 Browser could still check DNS record and compare it to global DB record. Attacker would need to fake domain, spoof DNS (these two are comparatively easy being MIM) but it would also need to poison global DB with false fingerprint. Global DB works like a crawler parsing zone records looking for fingerprints. There is no way to submit false fingerprints without access to zone records of particular domain. In addition, how many times were the DNS root servers hacked (not talking about DDOS here)? Haven't heard about one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in fact two questions: why use CAs instead of a global fingerprint database, and why use CAs instead of doing what SSH does. There's no global fingerprint database for SSH, it's in fact the very opposite.

In the SSH model, there's no built-in way to obtain the fingerprint of a server other than by connecting to it. The usual model for security is that when you connect to a server for the first time from a given client, you are prompted to manually verify the fingerprint, and when you connect again, the client verifies that the fingerprint hasn't changed. A common case where this model just works is when the client is on a laptop and you perform the first connection from inside the same trusted network that contains the server. Other than that, you are supposed to verify the fingerprint out of band, but most users just type “yes”. This system doesn't really scale; it's workable when you only connect to a handful of new hosts per year, but not for something like the web where you might connect to several new HTTPS sites every day.

If there was a global fingerprint database, then it would for all intents and purpose be a universal CA. The definition of a CA is that you trust it when it tells you that a certain public key K belongs to a certain entity E. In the SSL protocol, a CA tells you this by providing a certificate that contains a cryptographic assertion that K is the public key of E. A fingerprint database, where you look up E and get K or vice versa, is a different implementation of a trust relationship assertion. So with a global fingerprint database, we'd have an even bigger “too big to fail” database.

An approach that avoids the “too big to fail” problem is the [web of trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust) as used by PGP. The principle is that you know that K is the key of E because someone you know tells you so. This approach is reasonably well-suited to applications such as email, because many emails are sent between people who have a prior existing relationship, or who have common friends. It isn't applicable in a case like “I want to connect to this merchant's website”, where you'd never heard of this merchant before seeing a link to it on a price comparison site, but you want to know that the website belongs to a corporate entity that has been doing business for several years, and not to some drive-by scammer who'll take your money and be gone next week.

Having a single CA would raise concerns other than the risk to the integrity of the trust relationship database. When an entity registers a key, the CA is supposed to verify that the registrant has a valid claim to its purported identity (that the user registering a key for "Joe Bloggs" is really called Joe Bloggs, that the registrant for "Yoyodine, Inc." is indeed an authorized officer of Yoyodine, …), so the registrant cannot have privacy with respect to the CA. A choice of CA means that registrants have a choice of who they submit their private identity to. A state-run CA would be in a good place there because it knows the registrant's identity already — but which state? People may well want to declare identities that are not known to the state they live in. Another concern with a single CA is that it would have a monopoly on registration; having many CAs means that an entity is unlikely to be barred from participating.

A way to reduce the impact of a failure of a CA would be to routinely have keys certified by multiple CAs. This is something people often do in PGP-style web of trusts: I want to verify Alice's key, so I ask Bob, who tells me that the key is correct. But while I'm sure that it's Bob telling me this because I've verified his key, I don't completely trust Bob to have verified Alice's identity. So I also ask Carol, and Dan, and so on. With many converging presumptions, I get a better assurance that Alice is who she claims to be. In the same way, having a website's key certified by multiple CAs, and not revoked by any, would reduce the concerns that one of these CAs may have been compromised or may have been lax in verifying the registrant's identity. However, this would require updates to a lot of software that verifies SSL certificates and increase the cost of key registration.

Comment: So basically you're saying that the major reason we sacrifice our autonomy is to keep the scammers away  (so that they would require a legal proof before getting certified). My proposed system lacks that (there is no problem in getting certified scambank.cn), because the only proof you need is to own a domain to add a fingerprint. IMHO, we already pay for domains, storing a fingerprint could be part of that.

Comment: @User145678 Indeed, SSL registration could be tied to domain registration. That's what DNSSEC encourages. But domain registrars typically don't check the identity of registrants, and more importantly the identity of registrants is not what users care about. Using again the example of a web merchant, if I buy something on `yoyodyne.com`, I don't just want to know that I'm paying to the legitimate owner of the domain, I want to know that I'm paying to someone who has a reputation to maintain, who has an address where I can sue, ...

Comment: ICANN requires that all information in your registration be valid. In my particular case in order to register, I need to go through the bank and the registry checks whether the name I'm registering under is the same as the person who is paying for a domain. Furthermore, it should be more of a concern to banks and payment systems (e.g. implementing escrow system, validating account owners) and not enforced on a technological level. Basically, it's not a bazaars fault that you found a shady seller. You knew the risks and you still went there...

Comment: @User145678 Requires != checks. The only ways in which my DNS records are tied to my real identity is information that I declared but nobody checked, and the credit card I paid with (and that information might only have gone to a payment processor). Registrars aren't used to checking identities. Furthermore, there are so many registrars all over the place that it's hard to trust that all of them would check identities correctly — registrars are too small for their failure to matter!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how this would be a benefit. Currently we have many CA's which means that if one is broken for some reason (Diginotar, for example) we can simply (well, relatively simply) revoke the certs for that CA.

If you just had one big dB, what happens when it is broken, either deliberately or accidentally? You don't have any useful or quick fallback options.

Comment: Domain DNS fingerprint.